# Do async function get paused, if the user switch over another window

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, dom-events

Basically I created a JavaScript project

Here the problem is, when user switches to another window, the for loops continues to work, but async function get paused (I think this the only issue), because if you are on the same window it is working fine, but when you switches to another window, the next element of the array starts to get print, and get mixed with the previous element, which makes it look weird, so is there any solution for it?

JavaScript from the CodePen linked above:

```
// Numbers of skills stored in an array
let skillSet = ["DEVELOPER", "CODER", "BLOGGER", "PROGRAMMER", "WEB DEVELOPER", "DIGITAL MARKETER"];
// function to send each element from the given array
async function updateText() {
    let i
    skills.textContent = '';
    for (i = 0; i<skillSet.length; i++) {
        getText(skillSet[i]);
        if (skillSet[i].length <= 5) {
            await sleep(skillSet[i].length*420);
        } else {
            await sleep(skillSet[i].length*370);
        }
        if (i === skillSet.length-1) {
            i = -1;
        }
    }
}
// function to get each charachter and add to the html
async function getText(string) {
    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        await sleep(70);
        skills.textContent += string.charAt(i)
    }
    await sleep(700);
    deleteText(string)
}
// function to delete each character(from last) from the html 
async function deleteText(string) {
    for (let i = string.length; i > 0; i--) {
        await sleep(150);
        skills.textContent = skills.textContent.slice(0, -1);
    }
}
// function to pause the javascript, until the given task is done
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms));
}
// calling the function
updateText();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: (I've copied it into the question for you, though sometimes there are license issues doing that and I probably shouldn't have...)

Comment: actually, I am just a beginner in JavaScript, also used SO for the first time, thank you for changing the question in the correct order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers suspend or markedly slow down timers and some other background processing for tabs that don't have focus. It varies by browser; Chrome and its variants are fairly aggressive.

Your `sleep` function relies on `setTimeout`, so it's impacted by the fact that timers are de-prioritized (or entirely suspended).

Comment: Thank you for your response, but is there any solution for this one,  also can we write this code in more improvised manner, or this is the correct way to perform such tasks

Comment: @sarthakgupta - You can't really do anything about it, no. Browsers dialling back the processing consumed by inactive tabs is at the browser's discretion. All you can do is watch your assumptions: a timer won't necessarily fire after its given timeout period; it may be longer, possibly a lot longer. That's why when doing animations, for instance, you need to see how long it's been since the last time and update the animation appropriately for that actual time rather than how long you asked for. :-)